# Rest interface JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I need advice. It is possible to override that code using only JAX-RS?

```
final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();
final ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(httpClient);
client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().httpEngine(engine).build();
target = client.target(restConf.getFilestoreUrl());
fileStoreClient = target.proxy(FileStoreRest.class);
```

I've found many ways but all contain additional libraries and I only want libraries which wildfly 16 support.
Thank you for advice

Comment: You need an implementation. The proxy client feature is implementation specific. The JAX-RS specification has no such feature.

Comment: RESTEasy is Wildfly's JAX-RS implementation. So you should not have a problem using the above code in Wildfly.